# how make aplication like google map?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I'm planning to make an application like google maps only to a city in my country.
I want to use XNA WP7, but I get a lot of problems here

1. Is it possible that I detect a road just by detecting colors on the map that I created?
   or I must draw the line functions in XNA? and declare each point of the road?
2. second, whether I can control the image in XNA? how?
3. How do I get the position coordinate / pixel in the image rather than on the screen?

please give me an opinion, or give me a tutorial that relates to my project ..

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to use Google Maps in particular, or can you use Bing Maps? If you can use Bing Maps, then there's a [built in control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941096%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) that handles a lot of the hard work for you. You can download sample code on how to use the Bing Map control from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Comment: no, don't use bingmaps or google maps, i just use image and i detect a road by detecing colors on the image.

Comment: So this has nothing to do with maps and everything to do with image processing? You'll have to edit your question to make it clearer. How do you plan to get every road in your city?

Comment: yups,, nothing to do with maps.. but i want make application like google maps no using google maps.. i get every road with read color of the road.. that is posible?

Comment: How are you going to get every road?

Comment: I do not know exactly, but i want make like maze game..

Comment: Sorry, I can't really help you there. You don't want to use Bing Maps, but want to get all the roads in your city. The only way I can think of is manually adding all the roads (or at least the main ones)

Comment: in my city bing maps are still very bad, because that i could not wear it..
never mind, thank you very much.. if one day you have ideas you have ideas for my aplication please email me..

Comment: You could consider making the maze a bit simpler. For example, use Google maps to get a rough outline of the roads in your city and then create your maze based on that. Instead of every road, just go for main ones (and make up the rest). You'd still have to do it by hand though :/ If I come across anything that will help you, I'll comment back in this post :)